# counting the number of rows using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to count the number of rows which contain a certain value, There is three rows and I am working out the overall value of each one and putting into a variable so that I can later in the scripting print to the screen. I am only counting the rows within a certain cell range which is the first part of the code - to look for the first and last occurrence so that I can use these as the row numbers

```
Dim mediumStartRow As Integer
Dim mediumEndRow As Integer
Dim majVarCount As Integer
Dim minVarCount As Integer
Dim onTrackCount As Integer 

'Find the range of cells for Medium Projects, just gives the row number of the first occurnace and the last occurnace
mediumStartRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium Project", after:=Range("H21")).Row
mediumEndRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium Project", after:=Range("H21"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
MsgBox "First and Last Row for Medium Projects: " & mediumStartRow & mediumEndRow

    majVarCount = 0
    minVarCount = 0
    onTrackCount = 0

    With Range("AS:AU" & mediumStartRow)
        If Value = "Major Variance" Then
            majVarCount = Rows.Count
            Else
            If Value = "Minor Variance" Then
                minVarCount = Rows.Count
                Else
                If Value = "On Track" Then
                    onTrackCount = Rows.Count
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Do Until Range("AS:AU" & mediumEndRow)
        Loop
    End With

    MsgBox "Major Project Count: " & majVarCount
```

above it the code I have so far, but I seem to be getting a Run-Time Error - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed - on the line

```
With Range("AS:AU" & mediumStartRow)
```

Any clues on how to fix

Comment: You are not using a start row number sou you are looking for a range AS:AU2000.  Change to `With Range("AS1:AU" & mediumStartRow)`

Comment: @Scott Craner I cant use that as the rows I want to start count from would always have a different first row everytime I run the script, so I done a bit of script to find the first occurrence and last occurrence i.e. mediumStartRow and mediumEndRow

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the first and the last row number in the range statement. I.e.

```
With Range("AS" & mediumStartRow & ":AU" & mediumEndRow)
```

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/2119523/s%c3%b8ren-holten-hansen      that has gotten rid of that error and have amended the row  'Do Until Range("AS:AU" & mediumEndRow)' to reflect your comment so that it appears as 'Do Until Range("AS" & mediumEndRow & ":AU" & mediumEndRow)' but I get a run-time error Type mismatch

Comment: I think that may be a new question. As your code is in this question, I cannot see the purpose of the `DO` `LOOP` statement.